# Which file format starts with 0xAD 0xE1?

Tags: jpeg, file-format

A friend of mine has a collection of `.jpg` that cannot be opened because they start with `0xAD 0xE1` (so says GIMP).

Any idea which file format these may be?

Comment: A quick look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Magic_numbers_in_files) doesn't show that sequence. Try running the `file` command on your file to see what it thinks (assuming you're on Linux).

Comment: @Chris On Linux, the command `file` returns with the result: **data**.

Comment: Do you have more context info (Mac? Machine word order? taken from SD card in game console? Stuff like that) if you upload it somewhere I might take a stab at guessing the origin

Comment: Yup, [TrID](http://mark0.net/onlinetrid.aspx) also returns nothing (useful). Are those the *only* two bytes the files have in common or are there any more (is the third byte different)?

Comment: What's the next 20-30 bytes of the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be the FEE1DEAD code used by Linux reboot() syscall.

> [FEE1DEAD    Used by Linux reboot() syscall
>            Seen in PowerPC Mach-O binaries on Apple Inc.‘s Mac OS X platform.](http://codereflect.com/2010/12/31/magic-debug-values/)

That is, on a machine with suitably swapped byte order, 0xAD 0xE1 might be read in that order

Comment: gotta give you one for creativity.

Answer (score 0):

These definitely aren't jpg image formats or any [common image format](http://www.mikekunz.com/image_file_header.html) for that matter... I think a better question to ask is where your friend got these images or how he created them?

Comment: Heck, digging further it seems that it isn't any common file header if we can trust this link: http://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html